# Pass URL as get parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass u url as parameter to a get method.
I defined a route that accepts a {*url} parameter so I can send "/" characters without it separating my parameter.
As soon as there is a ":" in the url (like in http: or localhost:3857 for example), the method never gets hit.

The Html.ActionLink method escapes it's parameter itself, but it doesn't seem to escape the ':'. I cannot escape it manually because then the escape characters get escaped by the very same Html.Actionlink method.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Use EncodeUrl before you pass it, and then decode it on the other side.

Comment: I don't know about any EncodeUrl (where can I find it) but I did try HttpUtility.UrlEncode and HttpUtility.UrlPathencode. They both end up routing me to a (non existing) destination file rather then my method :(

Comment: HtmlTextWriter.EncodeUrl Method

Performs minimal URL encoding by converting spaces in the specified URL to the string "%20".

spaces are not my problem

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.encodeurl(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. I ended up removing the Html.ActionLink and replaced it with:

```
<a href="Movies?id=@item.ID">@item.Title</a>
```

@item.ID is a url returned from the netflix api, example http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/series/70021357/seasons/70021357. Now my url looks like this - /Home/Movies?id=http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/series/70021357/seasons/70021357, and I just used Request.QueryString to get the value in the controller:

```
Request.QueryString.Get("id")
```

Probably not ideal but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but you could replace the ':' with '%3A' (which is the escaped form), and see what the ActionLink does with it. If it's escaped once more, you'd have to replace the twice-escaped version back to ':' at the server, otherwise just replace '%3A' back to ':'